# how render html through controller to view in laravel using ajax

Tags: laravel, foreach, pagination

Can anyone solve my problem? I am using pagination in laravel by Ajax call.

***Here is my*** `Controller` ***code.***

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Purpose;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function fetch_purpose(Request $request)
    {

         $p = Purpose::simplePaginate(3);
         return view('admin.pagi.purpose_pagi', compact('p'))->render();
   

    }
}
```

***Here is my*** `purpose_pagi.blade.php` ***code.***

```
{{ $p->links()  }}
<h3>Purpose</h3>
@foreach($p as $purpose) 

    <tr id="p_row{{$purpose->id}}">
        <td>{{ $purpose->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$purpose->category}}</td>
    
        <td>

        <button  id="{{$purpose->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info edit_p_modal" data-toggle="modal" category="{{$purpose->category}}" >Edit</button>
        <button id="p_del"  del_id="{{$purpose->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger sp_del"  >Delete</button></td>
        
    </tr>
    
@endforeach
```

***The above code work perfectly. but below code does not work perfectly. just*** `@foreach` ***section render & below*** `@foreach`  ***code does not*** `render`

```
@foreach($p as $purpose) 

    <tr id="p_row{{$purpose->id}}">
        <td>{{ $purpose->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$purpose->category}}</td>
    
        <td>

        <button  id="{{$purpose->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info edit_p_modal" data-toggle="modal" category="{{$purpose->category}}" >Edit</button>
        <button id="p_del"  del_id="{{$purpose->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger sp_del"  >Delete</button></td>
        
    </tr>
    
@endforeach
{{ $p->links()  }}
<h3>Purpose</h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have Solve the problem.**

The Below `Code`works perfectly

```
@foreach($p as $purpose) 

    <tr id="p_row{{$purpose->id}}">
        <td>{{ $purpose->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$purpose->category}}</td>
    
        <td>

        <button  id="{{$purpose->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info edit_p_modal" data-toggle="modal" category="{{$purpose->category}}" >Edit</button>
        <button id="p_del"  del_id="{{$purpose->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger sp_del"  >Delete</button></td>
        
    </tr>
    
@endforeach
<tr>
   <td>
       {{ $p->links()  }}
       <h3>Purpose</h3>
   </td>
</tr>
```